# Unit tests of Parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

Where can I find tests for the implementation of Parsec?

There aren't any on Parsec's [darcs repository](http://code.haskell.org/parsec3/).

Note: I'm not asking *how* to write tests for a Parsec parser, I'm looking for the tests of the Parsec library itself.

Comment: You might be too optimistic in assuming that there are tests. OTOH, the library is well-tested by its numerous users...

Comment: @JoachimBreitner, hmm, I'm new to Haskell, but is it normal for such big/popular projects to _not_ have tests?

Comment: It is a very old library, older than most of the fancy popular test frameworks – if that is an excuse. Also, Haskell’s type systems can already prevent a lot of problems, so you generally need less testing than in, say, Python.

Answer (score 1):

There was originally a test/benchmark suite for Parsec called pbench. It seems lost to the sands of time: http://web.archive.org/web/20030818092724/http://www.cs.uu.nl/people/daan/pbench.html

There's no current unit test/regression suite for Parsec that I know of. See discussion here: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/14479

A test suite *could* be built without much work by leaning on the one written for attoparsec: https://github.com/bos/attoparsec/tree/master/tests